# TEXT_DETECTION and multiple words returned

Tags: computer-vision, google-cloud-vision

Do you know how to retrieve text from an image, word by word rather than everything in one field? It's important to me to know the position of each word on the document and not position of all text.

Is this even supported yet?

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: In the returned response,
"description" would have '\n' between two sentences if they are in different lines.
"boundingPoly" is the rectangle covering the area of all text.

I also hope to get the position or rectangle of each line.
Further, I need the angle of the text

According the document, they seems not to be supported now.